# Preference performance optimization required?

Tags: android, performance, sharedpreferences

I have to read some preference values into an Adapter.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean value;
```

---

I call the following code in `getView()` (in the Adapter):

```
value = prefs.getBoolean("key"), false);
```

My question is: is it better to preload this value into memory and use it or can  I keep this code and Android will do that by itself?

Answer (score 1):

When using `SharedPreferences` in an app that has multiple modifications for some value, then it's better to modify the value in memory then at later point. You may save it into `SharedPreferences` ..

For example, your `Application` class may have this:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    public static boolean flag = false;
}
```

And in your `getView` method, you are doing multiple changes to the counter value, like this:

```
public class BrandCountriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ..
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //....
    MyApplication.flag = true;
    //....
    return convertView;
}
```

Then at some time in your app, you might save the `flag` value in your preferences:

```
prefs.putBoolean("key"), MyApplication.flag);
```

Comment: Glad I helped out ^.^

Answer (score 0):

The question is: how much times do you use

```
prefs.getBoolean("key"), false);
```

in your code?

If you do it one/two times may be

```
value = prefs.getBoolean("key"), false);
```

is enough, but if you get value from shared preferences **multiple** times preload will be faster.

Comment: Many times, because there is a lot of items, for each item I read value.